# Rebex sftpClient.Getfile throws System.IO.IOException in JAMS

Tags: c#, sftp, rebex

I have a very basic c# console app that sftps into a remote server, grabs a file, and throws it into a location on our end (that the console application is on).

When I run the application manually, it runs fine and gets the file successfully.  This is also true of when I run it in an automated task.

However we use jams and for some reason, when scheduled to run through that, it ends up throwing

```
System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.Console.GetBufferInfo(Boolean throwOnNoConsole, Boolean& succeeded)
   at System.Console.get_CursorLeft()
   at GrabDataCarve.Class1.OnTransferProgress(Object sender, SftpTransferProgressEventArgs e)
   at Rebex.Net.Sftp.CipxfYZ(Object , String , Stream , Int64 , Int64 )
   at Rebex.Net.Sftp.CipxfYZ(FileMode , Object , String , String , Int64 , Int64 , Int64 )
   at Rebex.Net.Sftp.GetFile(String remotePath, String localPath)
```

Would anyone know a way to resolve this?  (It seems that JAMS is running it without a console window open.. maybe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rebex SFTP can create a detailed communication log. Maybe it can help? See https://www.rebex.net/sftp.net/features/logging.aspx#logwriter for instruction how to create a log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, my initial thinking was incorrect.  It ended up simply being the sftp was denying the new ip and causing this error to be thrown.  It is now resolved by having the other server approve the new ip.